# Samsung CLP-310N printing horizontal lines and ink trail smear on laser printer

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

I recently pulled out an old Samsung laser printer, model CLP-310N

It seems to work fine for the most part, except on every single page, it leaves horizontal lines and a toner smudge. It even happens if I print blank sheets of paper from the computer.

I’ve tried removing all parts and cleaning everything (roller, drum, belt, etc.) but I still have the same issue. All parts seemed to be ok (without scratch or anything suspicious) but as I’m not really knowledgeable in printers, I would maybe not recognize a damaged roller, drum or so.

I've tried printing lots of blank pages to see if the smudge will decrease over time, but it does not seem to be fading at all. I tried replacing the toners and this did not change anything.

If I would know the exact part that is malfunctioning I would be able to replace it so any help would really be appreciated. Here's what it looks like (several images because it varies from page to page):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "horizontal": Are the lines parallel to or perpendicular to the direction the pages come out of the printer?

Comment: Can you add an image of the problem?  Just edit it a link to the image at a public sharing site like imgur.com.

Comment: I tought I did but it did not seem to work. Here are some images : https://imgur.com/VO9cFa7, https://imgur.com/LX36OgZ, https://imgur.com/oeEkvN3, https://imgur.com/JzAEFMz

Answer (score 0):

Replace the black toner cartridge.

As the lines are all in black, the problem is in a component that is only used for black. As far as I can tell, in your printer, only the toner cartridges are colour specific. Everything else (imaging unit, waste container, fuser, etc) is used for all 4 colours and hence cannot be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is excess toner on a transport roller or on the drum unit.

If possible, you can try and remove the toner and fuser unit (they might be built in together) and gently clean any excess toner from anywhere you can find it.

If this device is not expensive or under warranty, it is probably going to be cheaper to buy a new one than to get someone to service it.

As of the time of posting this answer, you can find the service manual for cleaning and dismantling your device here: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/450370/Samsung-Clp-310n.html#manual